# The reason why Alamofire.Manager can be written syntactically

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Why `Alamofire.Manager` can be written syntactically, even though there is no `Alamofire` class in the framework?

When I read Alamofire's README.md page, at Manager section in Advanced Usage chapter, it describes how to instantiate Alamofire's Manager class like the following:

```
// Instantiate the sharedInstance of the Manager class in Alamofire.
let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
manager.request(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!))

// Instantiate Alamofire's Manager class with default configuration.
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

When I looked in the Alamofire code, I noticed there is no class named Alamofire, while a class named Manager exists.

In Swift, Starting with a capital letter, it means it is a Class, Struct, or Enum (maybe more). Also, a specific case of an Enum is written like `SomeEnum.SpecificCase`.

I understand, for example, `Manager()` means instantiates Manager class, but this case, non-class `Alamofire` is put before `Manager`. I don't know why it can be written this way.

What parts of the Alamofire framework allows this notation? Is there any specific code in Alamofire enabling this instantiation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because Swift has namespace. You may want to read [NAMESPACE](http://en.swifter.tips/namespace/)

Every project/framework has a namespace, like `Alamofire`, `SwiftyJSON`, ... and the author of such frameworks decided to use free functions

So normally you don't need to use namespace

```
request(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!))
```

But there are chances other framework having the exact `request` method, so must use namespace to differentiate between the 2

```
Alamofire.request(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!))
```

Comment: Thank your for the reply! I didn't know Swift uses namespaces. As long as a framework is just imported, can we use the namespace syntax like `SomeFramework.SomeClass()`, without writing any specific code for enabling this syntax?

Comment: Thank you for the reference!